# ES2015の分割代入でオブジェクトとプロパティを両方定義したい

Tags: javascript

ES2015の分割代入で、
引数のオブジェクト自体の定義も一緒にすることは出来ますか？

```js
function test_es5(obj){
    var a = obj.a;
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(a);
}

function test_es2015({a}){
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    //console.log(obj); objも分割代入と一緒に定義する方法はありますか？
    console.log(a);
}

var obj = {a:100};
test_es5(obj);
test_es2015(obj);
```

Comment: 自分の知る限り方法がなく、`function f(obj) { const { a } = obj; }` ぐらいしか代替案が思いつかないので、何故やりたいのかを質問に追記すると良い回答が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: function f(obj) { const { a } = obj; }で、二つに分けるしか無いのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[言語仕様](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)を見る限りできません。関連する構文を抜き出すと

```
FormalParameter:
    BindingElement
BindingElement:
    SingleNameBinding
    BindingPattern Initializer(opt)
SingleNameBinding:
    BindingIdentifier Initializer(opt)
BindingPattern:
    ObjectBindingPattern
    ArrayBindingPattern
ObjectBindingPattern:
    { }
    { BindingPropertyList }
    { BindingPropertyList, }
ArrayBindingPattern:
    [ Elisionopt BindingRestElement(opt) ]
    [ BindingElementList ]
    [ BindingElementList, Elision(opt) BindingRestElement(opt) ]
```

となっていて、要するに

- 単純な識別子`obj`
- オブジェクトパターン`{ a }`
- 配列パターン`[ b ]`

の３種類だけが記述できるように定義されています。そのためこれらを混ぜ合わせることはできないようです。

Comment: 言語仕様で無かったのですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @leoffa 疑問が解消したようでしたら解決済みとしていただけたら幸いです。